# Unwanted space inbetween image and Heading

Tags: html, css

There is some space inbetween an image(that has a border) and a division below it. The image's id is varImg and there is space inbetween it and #div2. I've set both margin and padding on the image and the division but it didn't work.I'd really really appreciate an answer.

Here's my code:

```css
#first {
  background-image: url('themaogate.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 105%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#varImg {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 0 1.5in .5in 1.5in;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

jpg {
  line-height: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: black;
}

#div2 {
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <nav id="nav2" class="centerAlign">
    <ul id="ul1">
      <p>We offer a variety of services including:</p>
      <li><button onclick="document.getElementById('varImg').src='#.jpg'">Soccer</button></li>
      <li><button onclick="document.getElementById('varImg').src='#.jpg'">Tennis</button></li>
      <li><button onclick="document.getElementById('varImg').src='#.jpg'">Table Tennis</button></li>
      <li><button onclick="document.getElementById('varImg').src='#'">Tabata, Aerobics, Zumba, Workouts and Dance</button></li>
      <li><button onclick="document.getElementById('varImg').src='#.jpg'">Events and Team building</button></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <img id="varImg" src="">
</div>
<div id="div2">
  <h1>Welcome to The #!</h1>
  <img id="img1" src="#.jpg">
  <p>###</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [ask] and how to create a [MRE] that includes just the relevant code that is needed to reproduce the problem. You can [edit] you question to remove the HTML and CSS that is not needed so it is easier to help, and also so that your question is clearer and more helpful to other users in future also.

Answer (score 1):

Your `h1` inside `#div2` still has some top margin. Setting it to zero should fix it:

```css
#div2 h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

#first {
  background-image: url('themaogate.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 105%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}



div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#varImg {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 0 1.5in .5in 1.5in;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

jpg {
  line-height: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: black;
}

#div2 {
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <nav id="nav2" class="centerAlign">
    <ul id="ul1">
      <p>We offer a variety of services including:</p>
      <li><button onclick="document.getElementById('varImg').src='#.jpg'">Soccer</button></li>
      <li><button onclick="document.getElementById('varImg').src='#.jpg'">Tennis</button></li>
      <li><button onclick="document.getElementById('varImg').src='#.jpg'">Table Tennis</button></li>
      <li><button onclick="document.getElementById('varImg').src='#'">Tabata, Aerobics, Zumba, Workouts and Dance</button></li>
      <li><button onclick="document.getElementById('varImg').src='#.jpg'">Events and Team building</button></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <img id="varImg" src="">
</div>
<div id="div2">
  <h1>Welcome to The #!</h1>
  <img id="img1" src="#.jpg">
  <p>###</p>
</div>
```